# Open CV delay measure

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo, darknet, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm using openCV library with yolov3 and darknet in my project. My app has been written in C++ and it reads rtsp stream and look for a human on the stream. I run it on my Nvidia Jetson Nano and everything is fine but there is one small issue. I have noticeable delay in video analysis. When I run it and I appear in camera view area I can see ~20s lag.

I'm analising substream (720p 2fps) but on recognition I would like to capture the right moment of recognition on the main stream (1080p 15fps) which I record using ffmpg. To do so i need to (1) don't have delay on recognition or (2) measure this delay during recognition to define which second of main video I need to capture.
I suppose (1) is not possible.

Do you know if openCV has such an option to display this delay? How can I measure it?

p.s. This delay is not always the same. But I noticed it is from 10 to 20 s,

Thank you a lot for any help ;)

Comment: Are you using cpu to decode h264 encoded data coming by rtsp camera? When you just tried simple videostream via on vlc or opencv videocapture, do you still get such delay ?

Comment: No, when I see rtsp via vls it is ok. I'm using h.264 encoded stream

Comment: what about pure stream without yolov3 with opencv?

Answer (score 2):

It will be hard to sync the stream, as both fps and stream channels are different. And another problem it's the rtsp stream, openCV can skip a lot of frames caused by bootlenecks and you can't get them back.

You may find a answer if you look where is your bootleneck. Probably, as it's a deep learning algorithm, most of the gpu/cpu time will be in the detection algorithm.

What i would do is: Ignore the second stream and focus your code on the main stream, add some frames on a buffer and detect, if your counditions are reached, then you iterate over that buffer to save what you need.

ps: This can cause problems to, due to the time needed to save the buffer on disk. (Maybe create a Thread for this will help)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try your suggestions ;)